Expo create new project error when type npx create-expo-app
I try to create a new project for React Native using Expo but get an error, I write the following comands:
npx create-expo-app ✔ What is your app named? … Test 
✖ Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: npm pack expo-template-default@latest --dry-run --json exited with non-zero code: 1 
Error: npm pack expo-template-default@latest --dry-run --json exited with non-zero code: 1

I tried to reinstall node JS. Now it's node v20.13.1, npm v10.8.0. I work on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Nothing helped me.
When I write npm pack expo-template-default@latest --dry-run --json then see the following answer:
`
npm error code E404
npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz
npm error 404
npm error 404  'https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm error 404 This package name is not valid, because 
npm error 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm error 404
npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "E404",
    "summary": "Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz",
    "detail": "'https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-51.0.27.tgz' is not in this registry.\nThis package name is not valid, because \n 1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters\n\nNote that you can also install from a\ntarball, folder, http url, or git url."
  }
}

`
Has anyone faced this problem?
I have no idea how to fix it.
Thanks

I spend a few days to fix this problem.
As a result I found that need to change npm configurations, so I typed the following command and this fixed the problem.
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org


Try using yarn instead of npx, it worked for me. If yarn requires permissions; use sudo yarn.
So it should be something like this:
sudo yarn create expo-app appName --template blank

Thanks for the answer. I found another solution, possibly me answer below can help you as well.

Actually, you need to completely delete the node JS and it's path in the environment variable. Then try again it will work.
